# Old version of RStudio automatically reinstalled after an update

Tags: rstudio, reinstall

[image]

I have just updated the RStudio to the newest available version. Turning on the computer (Windows 10) the next day and launching RStudio I see that it is back to version 1.4.1106, that has somehow been automatically reinstalled.

I have tried uninstalling 1.4.1106 multiple times and installing both earlier and later versions, but every time I restart it is back to 1.4.1106. Please suggest how I can be able to fix this.

Comment: Maybe contact RStudio support, I don't think this community can do anything about that. Is this a work computer? Do you need IT permissions to update?

Comment: No I don't.. This is something that has to do with this particular computer and RStudio version, but thank you.

Comment: Same problem here (with exactly the same versions)!

Comment: I have not found a solution other than re-installing the new version every few days (when using the RStudio)

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same problem with a slightly different version. In my case I managed to find some logs which showed that corporate patch management was automatically installing a specific version regularly. If this is a corporate machine, I suggest investigating any software that may be able to do this on your behalf.